# Getting Error: comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to make a simple shiny app and used the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(MASS)
ui<-fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(sidebarLayout(
    sliderInput(inputId = "num",label = "choose number of items to   display",min=1,max=25,value=5))),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("head"))


)
server<-function(input,output){

  inp<-reactive({switch(input$num)})

  output$head<-renderTable({head(painters,inp)})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

When I execute it, I get the following error

```
ERROR:comparison (3) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: If `inp` is a reactive, you should use it as `inp()` in the next line

Comment: @warmoverflow tried that too; got a new error:   ` length(n) == 1L is not TRUE `

Comment: However, doing away with the variable 'inp' and using

  `output$head<-renderTable({head(painters,input$num)})`

did away with the error altogether

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this....it looks like it might be a typo or something similar